# node commander options are undefined

Tags: node.js, node-commander

I'm having trouble using commander:
https://github.com/tj/commander.js/

```
program
    .command('school')
    .arguments("<year>")
    .option("--month <month>", "specify month")
    .parse(process.argv)
    .action(function (year) {
        console.log(`the year is ${year} and the month is ${program.month}`);
    });
```

I don't know why but `program.month` is undefined even when i run with `--month 12`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `program.commands[0].month` instead of `program.month`
It's weird that you should access the variable like this though.

Maybe you can get `month` via `.action` arguments? Not really familiar with commander myself.

Answer (score 2):

The `month` option in your example has been added to the `school` (sub)command, not to the program. The action handler is passed an extra parameter to allow you to conveniently access its options (as speculated by @GiveMeAllYourCats).

```js
program
  .command('school')
  .arguments("<year>")
  .option("--month <month>", "specify month")
  .action(function (year, options) {
      console.log(`the year is ${year} and the month is ${options.month}`);
  });
program.parse(process.argv);
```

```sh
$ node index.js school --month=3 2020
the year is 2020 and the month is 3
```